# Alert system with tailwindcss and preline

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

I'm making alerts system which currently looks like this

```
function notification(type, msg) {
    let popups = { ["error"]: `
    <div id="dismiss-alert" class="hs-removing:translate-x-5 hs-removing:opacity-0 transition duration-300 bg-teal-50 border border-teal-200 text-sm text-teal-800 rounded-lg p-4 dark:bg-teal-800/10 dark:border-teal-900 dark:text-teal-500" role="alert">
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="flex-shrink-0">
            <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-4 w-4 text-blue-600 mt-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path d="M12 22c5.523 0 10-4.477 10-10S17.523 2 12 2 2 6.477 2 12s4.477 10 10 10z"/><path d="m9 12 2 2 4-4"/></svg>
            </div>
            <div class="ms-2">
            <div class="text-sm font-medium">
                File has been successfully uploaded.
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ps-3 ms-auto">
            <div class="-mx-1.5 -my-1.5">
                <button type="button" class="inline-flex bg-teal-50 rounded-lg p-1.5 text-teal-500 hover:bg-teal-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-teal-50 focus:ring-teal-600 dark:bg-transparent dark:hover:bg-teal-800/50 dark:text-teal-600" data-hs-remove-element="#dismiss-alert">
                <span class="sr-only">Dismiss</span>
                <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path d="M18 6 6 18"/><path d="m6 6 12 12"/></svg>
                </button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
    } 
    $("#notifs").append(popups[type]);
}
```

But the problem is that if element was not in window when it was loaded dismiss button won't work (error is element from preline but I cannot copy it since I use ` for multi-line string)

I've tried to run tailwindcss build command but its just for the style functionality won't update

EDIT:

Explanation about the problem.
So I have a login page. When there is incorrect info inputed and user clicked on submit page should add a notification above the "card" to warn user that info is not correct.

Because I use tailwindcss, I use their preset for alert aka notification but it cannot be closed when clicked on X button since it is not registered after being added trough js script.

They also have preset (plugin) for that dismiss button for their alert so I need somehow to "refresh" it so it detects new alert on page.